# Largest allocatable array in VC++ 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

Does anyone what the largest array is that I can allocate in Visual C++ 2010? The maximum number of elements, I mean. Can I do something like int tarray [unsigned long], where unsigned long is some unsigned number larger than a 32-bit integer?

Comment: Are you using the 32-bit or 64-bit compiler?

Comment: It's set to 64-bit output.

Comment: Note that in visual studio, `unsigned long` is a 32 bit integer.  Maybe you meant `unsigned long long` or `long long` or `size_t` or `ptrdiff_t` or...